.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(...)) adds opacity on the round corners
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(...)) adds annoying opacity to the rounded corners:
ZStack{
   Color.red
   Color.yellow
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))

result:

But I expect full yellow rounded rectangle, without orange borders.
Only solution I found for now:
ZStack{
    Color.red
    Color.yellow
    Color.yellow
    Color.yellow
    Color.yellow
    Color.yellow
    Color.yellow
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))

Bring result:

Please note that this is simplified example.

What is your question? You already found a solution. What's wrong with it? Does it not work in your actual scenario? Then please show an example that is more representative of your actual scenario.

Also, I cannot reproduce the problem in the first place. I changed the simulator (iPhone 15 Pro Max, iOS 17.4) size to pixel accurate, and inspected the pixels using Digital Color Meter, and don't see any red. How did you produce that screenshot?

I was in fact able to reproduce your issue by running on an iPhone 15 simulator, taking a screenshot and examining this in an image editor.
The simplest workaround is to add either .compositingGroup() or .drawingGroup() to the ZStack:
ZStack {
    Color.red
    Color.yellow
}
.compositingGroup() // or .drawingGroup()
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
.border(.black.opacity(0.2))

Alternatively, you could apply nominal padding and then add an overlay to stroke the border using the same shape:
ZStack {
    Color.red
    Color.yellow
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
.padding(0.5)
.overlay {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
        .strokeBorder(.yellow)
}

If you don't mind the stroked outline going outside the frame by half the linewidth, then you can just stroke it without the padding:
ZStack {
    Color.red
    Color.yellow
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
.overlay {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
        .stroke(.yellow)
}

